# Error compiling, maybe due to cls file?

Tags: compiling, aastex

I have a file that's like the following, which uses the .cls file from [here](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/aastex/aastex62.cls):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex62}
\pdfoutput=1 %for arXiv submission
\usepackage{amsmath,amstext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[figure,figure*]{hypcap}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\vdag}{(v)^\dagger}
\newcommand\aastex{AAS\TeX}
\newcommand\latex{La\TeX}



\begin{document}
hi

\end{document}
```

My issue is, when I load the file, it pauses at \begin{document} with nothing but a "?" for a reason why something is wrong.  If I press enter, the whole file opens normally other than this.  However, if I try to upload this to Overleaf, I get a compiling error of "file 'aastex3.cls' not found."  As such I suspect the two are related, but can't figure out what is wrong, and can't find anything on the Internet telling me what this file would be that's crucial yet missing.

Thoughts appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As correctly asserted by David Carlisle below caption is not compatible with revtex and thus aastex. We get this question all the time (I should put up a FAQ). This TeX.SE answer is my useful reply for those who also want to use subfig (i.e., stop subfig from loading caption): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381701/subcaption-package-error-aastex61/381712

Answer (score 3):

The error message is not just a `?` it says

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \longtable* already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16 \begin{document}

?
```

You can simplify the example to

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex62}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
hi

\end{document}
```

Note the caption package does warn of possible problems, the log file shows

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

so the recommended way would be to not load `caption` and use the revtex mechanisms for controlling floats